# Ошибка при работе с DataGridView

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview

Добрый день. У меня есть на главной форме кнопка, по нажатию на которую открывается другая форма. При открытии этой формы я заполняю DataGridView данными из БД.

```
int bonus = 0;
private void ClientsLoad(int b)
    {
        CommandText = "SELECT Clients_info.Id, Clients_info.Surname+' 
'+Left(Clients_info.Name,1)+'.'+Left(Clients_info.Patronymic,1)+'.', 
Clients_info.Phone_number FROM Clients_info INNER JOIN Bonus_card ON 
Bonus_card.Id = Clients_info.Id_bonus_card WHERE (Clients_info.SMS_sending =
1) AND Bonus_card.Accrued_bonuses >= " + b.ToString() + " AND Bonus_card.Id >
1;";
        dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        myCommand = new SqlCommand(CommandText, myConnection);
        mySqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);
        myDataSet = new DataSet();
        mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet);
        if (myDataSet.Tables.Count > 0)
            dataGridView1.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    }

private void Form_SMSSending_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Left = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width / 2 - this.Width / 2;
        this.Top = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height / 2 - this.Height / 2;
        ClientsLoad(bonus);
        if (dataGridView1.Columns.Count < 4)
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(SMS_check);
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 45;
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "№ п/п";
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "ФИО";
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Телефон";
        dataGridView1.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Выбрать";
    }
```

Так вот, как видно из кода, у меня получается 4 столбца. Но при закрытии формы и при повторном открытии заголовки 3 и 0 столбца меняются местами. Не могу понять почему. Попробовал полностью очищать при закрытии DGV так:

```
private void Form_SMS_Sending_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
        myDataSet.Clear();
        dataGridView1.SelectAll();
        dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
        dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
}
```

И так:

```
private void Form_SMS_Sending_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    while (dataGridView1.Columns.Count != 0)
    {
            dataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1);
    }
}
```

Но в таком случае повторное открытие заканчивается ошибкой на строчке:
dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 45;
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить первую проблему и в чем загвоздка со второй? 
P.S. По поводу второй, такое ощущение, что кода я удалил все столбцы, то повторно не смог использовать эти же индексы столбцов, как при удалении записи в БД. Но с такой проблемой я еще ни разу не сталкивался

Comment: Не могу воспроизвести Вашу проблему. Какую ошибку Вы получаете на строке `dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 45`? `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`?

Comment: я сейчас просто сижу за компьютером без visual Studio. Ошибка - что-то там связано с экземпляром класса. Я завтра более точно напишу по этому поводу. А с первым случаем помочь не можете?

Comment: Вот ошибка дословно: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."

Comment: значит коллекция колонок у вас пустая. Вам нужно перед обращением к индексатору проверить на `null`.

Comment: Но в таком случае, на моменте

if (dataGridView1.Columns.Count < 4)
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(SMS_check);

Я проверил, до добавления столбца количество столбцов было 3, а после стало 4. А на след. строчке вылезла вышеуказанная ошибка